# StatusBarFrame in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, ios11

getting the statusBarFrame doesn't appear to return the correct value in iOS 11. I realize there may be a nicer way of dealing with this in the future using the Safe Area but right now I really need to get the statusBarFrame to work as it did before iOS 11. Here's how I usually get it.

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
```

I'v verified that my app works properly before iOS 11. But in iOS 11 it appears to be backwards; for example, for an iPhone in portrait it should 20 and in landscape 0. But it returns 0 in portrait and 20 in landscape.

I've read all the posts regarding status bar issues and none address this problem.

I think it appears to be a timing issue. I wrapped the code that uses the statusBarFrame in a DispatchQueue.main.async {} closure and it works fine. I would consider this more of a bandaid. Still hoping for a proper solution.

Suggestions appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set background color for status bar during application launch or during viewDidLoad of your view controller. Here it works for me, in following ways.

```
extension UIApplication {

    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    }

}

// Set upon application launch, if you've application based status bar
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return true
    }
}


or 
// Set it from your view controller if you've view controller based statusbar
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

}
```

Here is result:

[image]